# Template parse errors angular 8

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm working with angular 8 i want to display a popup with angular material this is what i did :

In my Html :

```html
<button (click)="myDia.open()">Open it</button>

Result: {{result | json}}

<my-dialog (result)="result = $event" #myDia>
  <h1 mat-dialog-title>Dialog Title</h1>
  <mat-dialog-content>
      Content
  </mat-dialog-content>
  <mat-dialog-actions>
      <button mat-button (click)="myDia.close()">Cancel</button>
      <button mat-button (click)="myDia.close({foo:'bar'})">Confirm</button>
  </mat-dialog-actions>
</my-dialog>
```

And this is the Ts file :

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-dialog',
  template: `
  <ng-template>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </ng-template>
  `
})


export class MyDialogComponent {
  @ViewChild(TemplateRef)
  private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>;

  @Output()
  result = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<any>;

  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {}

  open() {
      this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(this.templateRef);

      this.dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(val => {
          this.result.emit(val);
      });
  }

  close(val: any) {
      this.dialogRef.close(val);
  }

}
```

I have a problem in this line :

```
  @ViewChild(TemplateRef)
```

The error is :

> Expected 2 arguments, but got 1
>   An argument for 'opts' was not provided.

I have added in my app.module.ts :

```js
import { MyDialogComponent } from './pages/interfacage/test/test.component';
```

So how can i solve this problem.

I'am using this tuto [path](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-tp5aej?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

From Angular 8, you need to add `{ static: true }` in **ViewChild**

Try:

```
@ViewChild('TemplateRef', { static: true }) TemplateRef: any;
```

Comment: good but in chrome i have a problem :Template parse errors:
'my-dialog' is not a known element:
1. If 'my-dialog' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'my-dialog' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
Result: {{result | json}}

Comment: `'TemplateRef'` => `TemplateRef`

Comment: @HsuanLee where we put this

Answer (score 0):

Now it work in Angular8

```
    @ViewChild(TemplateRef, {static: false})
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>;
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-yqcfpj?file=app/app.component.html

---

Comment: it is okey for template ref but i have an error in my console : Template parse errors: 'my-dialog' is not a known element: 1. If 'my-dialog' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module. 2. If 'my-dialog' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. (" Result: {{result | json}

Comment: @mecabmecab95 Are you configuring entryComponents correctly?  https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#configuring-dialog-content-via-code-entrycomponents-code-

Comment: i have added import { MyDialogComponent } from './pages/interfacage/test/test.component';
in the app.module.ts  and  declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        MyDialogComponent

    ],   i'm using this tuto  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-yqcfpj?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: If you are using lazy loading, you need to declare in the lazy load module.